# How to handle current language? Always in URL, or session?

Tags: php, language-agnostic

Im planning to add language feature to my site. I can see two ways:

- storing language in the url, so always www.mysite.com/en/introduce, www.mysite.com/en/home, or if 1st parameter is missing, just use the default. Its good for bookmark, but very hard to implement to all available links
- storing in session. Way much easier, but users may gets confused not seeing the language in the URL.

I would say: session. What would you say? Any experiences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want all your pages to be indexed by search engines, you'll have put the language parameter in the URL.

If you're producing more something like Facebook where a user needs to be logged in to receive content in his personalized language, use sessions.

Comment: I am not familiar with this language implementation but have a question. Can't we use both together?

Comment: @Soft Sure. Each localized version of a page can have a unique URL with the language in the URL, with a session/cookie value being used to redirect the user to "his" language if necessary. The point is, if the pages are public and should be indexed by search engines, you need to give each a unique URL.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the first method togetter with a url rewrite engine.

F.e. when using RewriteEngine for Apache you could add this line to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])/([a-zA-Z]*)$ content.php?culture=$1&content=$2
```

and even this can work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])/([a-zA-Z]*)$ $2.php?culture=$1
```

Comment: idd, visitor will browse to www.mysite.com/en/home, this will be converted to www.mysite.com/content.php?culture=en&content=home (first option) or www.mysite.com/home.php?culture=en (second option). Also note that these conversions are invisible to the visitor. Lookup RewriteEngine or url rewriting

Answer (score 2):

You want to put your language as part of the url, otherwise google won't be able to index it for different countries. Also, they might think you have two types of content on the same page.

I would store it in session if there's only some parts of content changing as it's easier to implement if you're just changing i.e. contact details for the company based on what country the user is coming from. But as a general rule, give it a separate url either using .htaccess or your routing system.

Answer (score 1):

Regular users don't look at URL and change the parameters from there. Normal users are point and click. Keep the language selection somewhere visible on the page and also in the user settings. This is not something that a user will want to change several times during a visit. We are talking about a setting that you can ask and set on the first visit. Currently I hate the way the google does it using my IP, assuming (wrong) that if I am entering from Norway I definitely speak Norwegian and I can handle finding in Norwegian menus the English version. I do like the way Etsy.com is doing it, they ask you on the first visit what is your preferred language, currency and so on. If you accept them good, but you can change them right there without having to navigate to a menu. In my opinion go for cookies or session instead of polluting the URL.